# computed and specified values for %

Tags: css

I think for % units, computed and specified values are not always same. As I can't check these values, I need expert comment here from CSS community.

In this example [CSS3 Cascade section 5.5](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-cascade/#stages-examples) specified and computed values for % width is same but I feel this is not true for % font-size. I have given one example below, please correct me  if my observation is wrong.

```
#parent{
width:200px;
font-size:10px;
}

#child{
width: 200%;
font-size: 200%;
}
```

for child:
I believe in case of width, specified value and computed value will be 200%. Used value will be 400px.

While in case of font-size, specified value will differ from computed value. In this case font-size doesn't depend of the layout so computed value will be 20px instead of 200%.

> Is below observation correct for above example?

for child width

```
specified: 200%
computed: 200%
used: 400px
```

for child font-size

```
specified: 200%
computed: 20px
used: 20px
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: em is relative to the size-specification of its parents

Comment: Is my observation is correct?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your observation is accurate.

However, you should have just ran the code in the browser and saw the resulting output, instead of asking us for verification. Would have been faster for you and us.

Comment: resulting output is actual value not specified or computed, So I can't check.

Comment: In fact, window.getComputedStyle also provides used value instead of specified or computed.